# "Fatal scripting error: Command Out is not supported" in PostDeployment Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd, database-project

In my database project I have Post-Deployment script which looks like this:

```
:r "..\PostDeployment\InitialScript1.sql"
:r "..\PostDeployment\InitialScript2.sql"
:r "..\PostDeployment\InitialScript3.sql"
```

It works great and successfully calls needed scripts.

But I have a table on SQL Server which contains a list of additional scripts that need to be executed during deployment and executed only once. So I want to add to my Post-Deployment script next code

```
:out "..\PostDeployment\RunAdditionalScripts.sql"
SELECT N':r "..\PostDeployment\SingleScripts\' + ste.Script_Name + '"
UPDATE ScriptsToExec SET IsExecuted = 1 WHERE Script_Name = ''' + ste.Script_Name + '''' 
FROM ScriptsToExec AS ste WHERE ste.IsExecuted = 0
:r "..\PostDeployment\RunAdditionalScripts.sql"
```

Which, I hope, will generate me a file RunAdditionalScripts.sql with next code

```
:r "..\PostDeployment\SingleScripts\AdditionalScript1.sql"
UPDATE ScriptsToExec SET IsExecuted = 1 WHERE Script_Name = 'AdditionalScript1.sql' 
:r "..\PostDeployment\SingleScripts\AdditionalScript2.sql"
UPDATE ScriptsToExec SET IsExecuted = 1 WHERE Script_Name = 'AdditionalScript2.sql' 
:r "..\PostDeployment\SingleScripts\AdditionalScript3.sql"
UPDATE ScriptsToExec SET IsExecuted = 1 WHERE Script_Name = 'AdditionalScript3.sql'
```

But when i'm trying to add :out command I get error "Fatal scripting error: Command Out is not supported" (SQLCMD Mode is turned on). So, how can I get this work or how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Did you try this: Grant rigths to TEMP directory
http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-linked-servers.htm

Comment: Pretty sure "OUT" isn't supported (along with a handful of other SQLCMD commands). If this is truly a one-off, I'd either add the scripts as a one-shot for your next release or look into some post-build process that can run scripts like this.